Knowing Size Of Page In Flet
to be clearly I did simple my code,
As you Know for run code in Flet we have function call main as shown in below
def main(page:Page):
    print(page.width,"Page width Size")
    page.add(Main_page())

app(target=main )

as you know the second line of code print the width of screen,Result (392.72 Page width Size
)
Also I have another class name is Main_page as shown below
class Main_page(UserControl):
   print(Page.width, "Page width Size Inside Class")

But i didn't get same result, the result is <property object at 0x00000114832D6160> Page width Size Inside Class
My question is that How I can Page.width value in another class.
